# DirectShow graph separate Avi and Wav (play back, not saving)?

Tags: audio, directshow

I am new to Direct Show. What I am trying to do is use one iGraphBuilder object, to play both a silent Avi video, and a separate Wav file at the same time. I can't merge the two into one video, but I would like it to appear as if they were.

Is there any way to go about using one set of filters to run an avi and wav file concurrently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this both ways: by adding two separate chains into the same graph, or using two separate filter graphs.

The first method will give you a graph like this:

[image]

Second method will get you two graphs:

[image]
[image]

The first approach has advantage that you have lipsync between video and audio and you control the graphs as a single playback object. The other method's advantage is ability to control video and audio separately, including stopping and changing files independently one from the other.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! I am going to go and read up on GraphStudioNext and see if I can re-create this.

Comment: I have created a similar graph to the one you have made here, but I am wondering if there is a way to create a graph that does not rely on a hard coded path to the video file. Is there a way to make it accept a path when it is called within the program? I have not found much documentation on the program.

Comment: Of course you can provide path programmatically, and it's documented:  see [`IFileSourceFilter::Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).